# How do I move the 2d cursor in the graph editor?

Tags: animation, shortcut, graph-editor

I used to be able to move the 2d cursor in the graph editor by clicking on the blue number in the timeline but now it won't move the horizontal blue line. Only the vertical one. Anyone know how I'm supposed to do this now?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the horizontal blue line is a Z transform curve (the 0 line is also blue), you can't move it with the blue cursor

Comment: SHIFT + RMB in the grapheditor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways.

- You can move the frame (X) cursor by dragging in the top bar
- You can place the cursor by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>–Right-mouse
- You can set the cursor in the sidebar in the cursor tab:

[image: Sidebar showing cursor tab]

You can also use the buttons in the cursor tab to move the cursor.